# ggplot call changes locale LC_NUMERIC variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling with a strange behaviour of R/ggplot.

Starting a fresh R session and calling `sessionInfo()` gives

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Linux Mint 19
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /home/nicolai/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so LAPACK:
>   /home/nicolai/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
>   LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8     [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
>   LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
>   LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] RevoUtils_11.0.1     RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.18
>   assertthat_0.2.0 dplyr_0.7.6      crayon_1.3.4     R6_2.2.2
>   grid_3.5.1       plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0      [9] magrittr_1.5
>   scales_0.5.0     ggplot2_3.0.0    pillar_1.3.0     rlang_0.2.1
>   lazyeval_0.2.1   rstudioapi_0.7   bindrcpp_0.2.2   [17] tools_3.5.1
>   glue_1.3.0       purrr_0.2.5      munsell_0.5.0    yaml_2.2.0
>   compiler_3.5.1   pkgconfig_2.0.1  colorspace_1.3-2 [25]
>   tidyselect_0.2.4 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_1.4.2

Notice how `LC_NUMERIC` is set to `C`.

Typing `1.2` returns

> 1.2

After calling the following two lines of code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5), aes(a, b)) + geom_point()
```

My R-session mysteriously changes the decimal separator from a dot to a comma. Typing `1.2` returns

> 1,2

All plots I generate have the comma as the decimal separator. Calling `sessionInfo()` returns

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Linux Mint 19
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /home/nicolai/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so LAPACK:
>   /home/nicolai/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
>   LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8         [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
>   LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8          LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8            [9]
>   LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] ggplot2_3.0.0        RevoUtils_11.0.1
>   RevoUtilsMath_11.0.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.18
>   rstudioapi_0.7   bindr_0.1.1      magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.4
>   munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.3-2 R6_2.2.2          [9] rlang_0.2.1
>   plyr_1.8.4       dplyr_0.7.6      tools_3.5.1      grid_3.5.1
>   gtable_0.2.0     withr_2.1.2      yaml_2.2.0       [17] lazyeval_0.2.1
>   assertthat_0.2.0 tibble_1.4.2     crayon_1.3.4     bindrcpp_0.2.2
>   purrr_0.2.5      glue_1.3.0       labeling_0.3     [25] compiler_3.5.1
>   pillar_1.3.0     scales_0.5.0     pkgconfig_2.0.1

Notice how the LC_NUMERIC value has changed. I assume this causes the change in the decimal separator, but I have no idea how that makes sense.

This is something that happened after installing a fresh Mint version together with a fresh, up-to-date R version.

Does someone have an idea of what could cause this?

Comment: I have just fixed the issue by appending "export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" to my .bashrc file.

Comment: Hi PejoPhylo, I have the exact same problem and spent a lot of time to come to the same conclusion as you. I reported the [problem here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4504) but in fact the problem happens with base `plot()` too so this is not ggplot2 specific.